# Twilio number to another twilio number call

Tags: twilio

I am developing contact center using twilio where my application get request from server to call contact center, so my application initiate a request to call contact center (Twilio enabled number) and contact center is twilio soft phone once the contact center accept a call my application initiate another request to call user so contact center person and user will be in conference. In my application **From** number is also a twilio enabled number. so my question is can I call one twilio enabled number to another twilio enabled number using java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve, but it is certainly possible to connect two Twilio numbers in a call. Those numbers will need to either dial onto a Twilio soft phone or a phone number connected to a real phone in order to connect two people.

I'd recommend taking a look at this [Java click to call tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/java/servlets) which should give you an idea of how to connect to one number, then generate the call to another number and give you a start in this.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank You, Philanash for your reply. I have read Java click to call tutorial. So just want one confirmation Click to Call scenario, what happen if Customer Care Agent also having Twilio enabled number means FROM and TO both number are Twilio enabled number.

Comment: In that case it is not a problem, Twilio numbers can call onto other Twilio numbers :)

Comment: Thank you, I will update you very soon after applying this approach.

Comment: My customer Care agent number (TO) is twilio trial number and from which I am calling to Agent that number (FROM) is paid twilio number but it is not connected. e.g. USER<---TWILIO FROM--->AGENT(TWILIO TO) so FROM no is paid but TO no is trial, twilio from to user is successfully place call but twilio from to Agent is getting application error. One more thing customer care is a twilio softphone.

Comment: You should be able to see the cause of the application error by checking the Monitor in your account portal for the account that is not working. Can you have a look and tell me the error?

Comment: Thanks Philnash. I am able to call now, having some problem in my code Response is not sending back now it is working fine now.